# Javascript - Error handling - Array of Promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

What would be the right way to handle an array of ajax responses? I mean, since it is an array of promises, what happens when one of those ajax calls fail?

```
$.when.apply($, array_of_promises).then(
    successCallback function(){
       // Loop over the arguments to control errors??
    },
    failCallback function(){
    }
);
```

Where would I be able to detect the error? Do I get it in the 'error handling function'? Do I have to check in the 'success function' looping over the argument variable for checking that all the ajax calls were successfully done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $.when.apply(array_of_promises)
> ```

Notice that the first argument of [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is missing here, pass a `$` or `null`.

> what happens when one of those ajax calls fail?

The [`jQuery.when` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) say:

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when,
>   the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object
>   that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been
>   passed. **The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the
>   Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the
>   Deferreds is rejected.** If the master Deferred is resolved, it is
>   passed the resolved values of all the Deferreds that were passed to
>   jQuery.when. For example, when the Deferreds are jQuery.ajax()
>   requests, the arguments will be the jqXHR objects for the requests, in
>   the order they were given in the argument list.
>
> In the multiple-Deferreds case where one of the Deferreds is rejected,
>   jQuery.when immediately fires the failCallbacks for its master
>   Deferred. Note that some of the Deferreds may still be unresolved at
>   that point. If you need to perform additional processing for this
>   case, such as canceling any unfinished ajax requests, you can keep
>   references to the underlying jqXHR objects in a closure and
>   inspect/cancel them in the failCallback.

> Where would I be able to detect the error? Do I get it in the 'error handling function'?

Yes.

> Do I have to check in the 'success function' looping over the argument variable for checking that all the ajax calls were successfully done?

No. If the error handler is called, the success function is not. The success function will only by called if there was no error.

Answer (score 1):

Deffered.then incorporates the `.done()` and `.fail()`. So my guess would be that you'd have your first callback as the `success/.done()` and the second as `error/.fail()`.

```
$.when.apply(array_of_promises).then(successCallback, failCallback);

successCallback function(){
    ...
}

failCallback function() {
    ...
}
```

Api - **[$.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)**

Comment: My point in this question is that what you get without errors is an array of responses. What you are saying is that because of one ajax call failed, all the further processed ajax calls are considered as failed too?

Comment: Hmmm, is see what you mean what you might need here is [deferred.always](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)